# sendDirect () method not working

Tags: omnet++

i place a code in my omnet++ project as

```
cMessage *data=new cMessage("data"); 
for (i=0;i<3;i++)
{
cModule *target=getParentModule()->getSubmodule("host[i]");
sendDirect(data,target,"radioIn");
scheduleAt(simTime(),data);
cancelEvent(data);
}
```

but it shows error **destination module pointer is NULL.**

i configure my wireless node as

```
simple wirelessnode
{
....
gates:
input radioIn @directIn;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many errors in your code:

1. In order to get pointer to one host from a vector of hosts you should indicate a number as a second argument of `getSubmodule()` method; so it should be like this:
    `getSubmodule("host",i)`
2. You mustn't send the same message second time! There is `dup()` method for `cMessage` class which make a new copy (new instance) of a message. I suggest making a copy just before using method `sendDirect()` and removing a spare original after `for` loop.
3. The `scheduleAt()` method is necessary only if you want to send a message to the same module. I guess that your intention is to send `data` message to other module, so `scheduleAt()` has to be removed from your code.
4. The `cancelEvent(data)` has to be removed too. This method removes *own* message from future event set. The `data` message has just been sent therefore you cannot remove it.

The corrected code:

```
cMessage *data = new cMessage("data"); 
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
   cModule *target = getParentModule()->getSubmodule("host", i);
   cMessage *dataCopy = data->dup();
   sendDirect(dataCopy, target, "radioIn");
}
delete data; // removing an original message
```